# Question about the Simon's algorithm

Tags: complexity-theory, information-theory, quantum-computing

This comes from trying to understand the "Simon's algorithm".

So we have a set of $2^n$ kets $|x_i \rangle$ one each for $i \in \{0,1\}^n$. Each $x_j \in \{0,1\}^n$. And we have the further constraint that $x_i = x_j$ iff $i = j + s \pmod{2} = j \oplus s$ (bitwise addition modulo $2$) for a certain $s \in \{0,1\}^n$. (so every $|x_k\rangle$ is guaranteed to have a second copy)

Now one has this state given as $\psi_a = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n}}\sum_{i \in \{0,1\}^n} |i\rangle|x_i\rangle $ So this is a state of some 2 qubit system.

- Given this I want to understand why a measurement on the second qubit would necessarily collapse this to the state, $\psi_b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |j\rangle + |j \oplus s\rangle)|x_j\rangle$ for some $j \in \{0,1\}^n$?

---

- Is this measurement of the second qubit state trying to measure some observable/Hermitian operator whose eigenstates are precisely these $\psi_b$s? Then it would make some sense that the only things one sees are these $\psi_b$ states.

But this would still not clarify the weird probability addition that is happening here as shown below.

---

One notes that the state $\psi_b$ will be obtained with a probability of $(\bar{\psi_b} \psi_a)^2 = (\frac{ 2}{ \sqrt{2^{n+1} }})^2 = 1/2^{n-1}$. These $\psi_b$s obviously do not span the entire $2^{2n}$ dimensional Hilbert space available to these two qubits. They are not a basis.

- But the probabilities don't add up rightly either $\sum_b ( \bar{\psi_b} \psi_a )^2 = 2$. Wonder is the interpretation of the fact that the probabilites over all these possibilities seem to add up to $2$!
- Some explanations I found say that these states $\psi_b$ being the only possibilities is forced because of the fact that the second qubit is being measured in the "computational basis". This argument is not clear to me.

Comment: In the future, use `\rangle` instead of `>` (and `\langle` instead of `<`).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I get all your questions. I'll try to answer according to my interpretation of what you are asking, and you can clarify if I got you wrong.

> - Given this I want to understand why a measurement on the second qubit would necessarily collapse this to the state, $\psi_b = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} ( |j\rangle + |j \oplus s\rangle)|x_j\rangle$ for some $j \in \{0,1\}^n$?

First, there is no second qubit, but a second system (of $n$ qubits). Next, consider $\psi_a$, and recall that for any $f(x_j)$ there are only two preimages $j$ and $j\oplus s$, then if you measure $f(x_j)$ at the second system, the first system must either be $j$ or $j\oplus s$.

> - Is this measurement of the second qubit state trying to measure some observable/Hermitian operator whose eigenstates are precisely these $\psi_b$s? Then it would make some sense that the only things one sees are these $\psi_b$ states.

Kind of. However, you don't measure $\vert\psi_a\rangle$ directly. There is another hadamard gate which is missing there. I.e., you measure
$$(H\otimes I) \left\vert\psi_a\right\rangle = \frac1{2^n}\sum_x\sum_i (-1)^{i\cdot x}\left\vert i\right\rangle\left\vert f(x)\right\rangle$$

Now if you re-arrange it properly, it should give
\begin{align*}
\frac1{2^n}\sum_{x\in\{0,1\}^n}\sum_i (-1)^{i\cdot x}\left\vert i\right\rangle\left\vert f(x)\right\rangle &=
\frac1{2^n}\sum_{j\in XS}\sum_i (-1)^{i\cdot j}\left\vert i\right\rangle\left\vert f(j)\right\rangle + (-1)^{i\cdot (j\oplus s)}\left\vert f(j\oplus s)\right\rangle \\
&=
 \frac1{2^n}\sum_{j\in XS}\sum_i \left ((-1)^{i\cdot j}+(-1)^{i\cdot j}(-1)^{i\cdot s}\right)\left\vert i\right\rangle\left\vert f(j)\right\rangle \\
&=
 \frac1{2^n}\sum_{j\in XS}\sum_i (-1)^{i\cdot j}\left(1+(-1)^{i\cdot s}\right)\left\vert i\right\rangle\left\vert f(j)\right\rangle 
\end{align*}
Where $XS\subseteq \{0,1\}^n$ is the largest subset such that if $j\in XS$ then $\forall j'\in XS, f(j)\ne f(j')$; so that the sum over $j$ is only over half the space and  we don't count twice $x=j$ and $x=j\oplus s$. But note that $f(j)=f(j\oplus s)$ which we use in the second transition.

The above shows that for any $i$ for which $s\cdot i=1 \mod 2$ there is a destructive interference that cancels these terms, and you are left with only $i$'s for which $s\cdot i=0 \mod 2$. Thus, any $i$ you will measure (at the first system) must satisfy $s\cdot i=0 \mod 2$.

Comment: Is there a $\vert x \rangle$ missing in your second equation? So are you basically saying that in that $(H \otimes I) \vert \psi_a \rangle \propto \sum_b \vert \psi_b \rangle$ ?

Comment: no, but the sum should be over $i$ not over $x$. I edited the answer.

Comment: up to the missing (and very important) phases!!!

Comment: Why do you think the phases are important here? It seems to me that what Simon's algorithms is relying on is the fact that $\vert <\psi_b \vert H \otimes I \vert \psi_a \rangle \vert ^2 $ is the same for all $b$ - right?

Comment: I mis-read you. Note that $\vert \psi_a \rangle = \sum_j \vert \psi_b(j)>$. But then you perform hadmard, and then the phases get into play. They are very important since they cause (or rather, explain) the destructive interference.

Comment: Why are you removing the $\sum_x$? The $I$ acts on the second system and keeps it invariant - right? $(H \otimes I) \vert \psi_a \rangle = \frac{1}{ 2^n} \sum_x (  \sum_i (H \vert i > = \sum_{j \in \{ 0,1\}^n} (-1)^{i.j} (1 + (-1)^{s.j} ) \vert j > ) ) \vert x \rangle $

Comment: You could have chosen to expand $(H \otimes I)\vert \psi_a \rangle$ in any arbitrary basis and then we could have gotten a different linear sum. This can't explain why only the $\psi_b$ states should be observed. Wave-functions collapse only to eigenstates of the observable. So the $\psi_b$s have to be eigenstaes of the observation being made to ensure that the observed states are only the $\psi_b$ states.